# Unable to log into ngrok network with password failure

Tags: ngrok

I have a remote site connected via a LTE modem and ngrok. It runs on Raspberry Pis.

My problem is that when I try and login I get a password failure (n.b the login prompt for account is correct).This could obviously be fixed if I travelled the 50 miles and reset the system but I was rather hoping that there was a way I could do it remotely!

Now the technical details;

a) ngrok did work with the remote connection before entering this failure mode
b) The site does do occasional file transfers and these appear to be working perfectly
c) One of the items in b) is the ngrok address which has not changed
d) The fault is repeated if I put in the wrong ngrok address

Is there any way to reset the link remotely?

(The logical explanation for all this is that ngrok has changed the connection parameters which I am not picking up correctly. I use 'curl -s localhost:4040/api/tunnels | jq -r .tunnels[0].public_url' at the remote end, which is then both e-mailed on change, and file transferred to another Pi. However today I could access the device without problems for several hours without any change to the login parameters and then it stopped working again.)

---

The remote unit has now been brought back to the house for testing so I am able to both use ngrok via the LTE modem and a direct ethernet connection.

I can confirm that the remote computer:
a) Can be logged into as normal via ethernet
b) ps ax | grep ngrok -> 613 ?  Ssl   12:19 /snap/ngrok/38/ngrok start --all --config=/home/pi/ngrok/config.yml (the old PID indicating that it has been running for some time)
c) The result of the method given previously for getting the tunnel address is unchanged from when it was working perfectly yesterday

Any suggestions on other tests to run?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is but, I think this [blog](https://blog.fomo.com/remotely-kill-ngrok-session/) might give you an idea of remote actions on a session.

Comment: Thanks for this but wouldn't the 'killlall' command have to be done at the remote end to which I currently have no access